# Images moving with parallax effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

I am attempting to build a parallax page. I have a lot of stuff going on in the code as this is new to me. The parallax effect is working properly however when i shorten the browser window in the live preview some of the items/images start moving upward as I make the screen shorter. I am wondering how to stop this and make the images stay in place when I make the window shorter. I have tried all positioning and it did nothing. Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" >
<script src="javascript/scroll.js" ></script>
<title>Kawasaki</title>
<meta name="description" content="Demonstration of grouping content in pure CSS parallax scrolling website">
</head>

<body>
<div class="parallax">
  <div id="group1" class="parallax__group">
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--mountains">
      <div  class="title"><img src="images/1x/mountains.png" width="2851" height="915" alt=""/></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="group2" class="parallax__group">
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--sky">
      <div class="title"><img src="images/1x/sky.png" width="2851" height="915" alt=""/></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="group3" class="parallax__group">
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--mid-trees">
      <div class="title"><img src="images/1x/mid-trees.png" width="2848" height="828" alt=""/></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="group4" class="parallax__group">
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--front-trees">
      <div class="title"><img src="images/1x/front-trees.png" width="2851" height="869" alt=""/></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <section id="middle-page" ></section>
  <img id="dirtbike" src="images/1x/dirtbike.png" alt="" > <img id="logo" src="images/1x/logo.png" alt="" >
  <div id="year">2020 KX 450f</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
.parallax {
  height: 500px; /* fallback for older browsers */
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-perspective: 300px;
  perspective: 300px;
}
.parallax__group {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px; /* fallback for older browsers */
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.parallax__layer--mid-trees {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(90px) scale(.8);
  transform: translateZ(78px) scale(.8);
}
.parallax__layer--front-trees {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(110px) scale(.7);
  transform: translateZ(110px) scale(.7);
}
.parallax__layer--sky {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);
  transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);
}
#middle-page {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px) scale(2);
  transform: translateZ(100px) scale(2);
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #171E17;
  top: 1600px;
  left: 1000px;
}
#dirtbike {
  position: absolute;
  height: 240px;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 750px;
  left: 1075px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(85px) scale(2);
  transform: translateZ(85px) scale(2);
}
#logo {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 5;
  top: -100px;
  left: 970px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
  transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2);
}
#year {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 150px;
  left: 1170px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
  transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2);
  color: #405740;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
  font-weight: 300;
}
/* Debugger styles - used to show the effect
  --------------------------------------------- */
.debug {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: .5em;
  z-index: 999;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .85);
  color: #fff;
  padding: .5em;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
.debug-on .parallax__group {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(800px, 0, -800px) rotateY(30deg);
  transform: translate3d(700px, 0, -800px) rotateY(30deg);
}
.debug-on .parallax__layer {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #000;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.parallax__group {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
/* demo styles
  --------------------------------------------- */
body, html {
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  font: 100% / 1.5 Arial;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.parallax {
  font-size: 200%;
}
/* centre the content in the parallax layers */
.title {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
/* style the groups
  --------------------------------------------- */
#group1 {
  z-index: 2; /* slide over group 2 */
}
#group1 .parallax__layer--mountains {
  background: none;
  top: 460px;
}
#group2 {
  z-index: 1; /* slide under groups 1 and 3 */
}
#group2 .parallax__layer--sky {
  background: none;
  top: -3700px;
}
#group3 {
  z-index: 4; /* slide over group 2 and 4 */
}
#group3 .parallax__layer--mid-trees {
  background: none;
  top: -4600px;
}
#group4 {
  z-index: 5; /* slide over group 2 and 4 */
}
#group4 .parallax__layer--front-trees {
  background: none;
  top: -7270px;
}
/* misc
  --------------------------------------------- */
.demo__info {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  bottom: 1vh;
  top: auto;
  font-size: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```
// JavaScript Document

var debugInput = document.querySelector("input");

function updateDebugState() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('debug-on', debugInput.checked);
}
debugInput.addEventListener("click", updateDebugState);
updateDebugState();



(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
  i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
  i[r] = i[r] || function () {
    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
  }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
  a = s.createElement(o),
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
  a.async = 1;
  a.src = g;
  m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
ga('create', 'UA-10812217-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```